# Python apply function to multiple dataframes with different data strucutre

Tags: python, pandas

I appreciate this might be a stupid question. I have a function called `read_files()` that reads two pandas dataframes but the data structure is slightly different in each dataframe. Hence different header, index_col, sheet_name etc. for each dataframe.

Is there any way to to rewrite this function so that it' shorter or more Pythonic?

```
  def read_files():
    input_location = r'C:\Users\name\Desktop\foobar\\'

    df1 = pd.read_excel(
                          input_location+'example1.xlsx', 
                          sheet_name='foo',
                          header=8,
                          index_col=2,
                       )
    
    df2 = pd.read_excel(
                          input_location+'example2.xlsx', 
                          header=11,
                          index_col=1,
                          skipfooter=10
                        )

    return df1, df2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can, for example, keep your parameters in a dict keyed by the file name

```
read_excel_params = {
    'example1.xlsx':dict( header=11,
                          index_col=1,
                          skipfooter=10),
    'example2.xlsx':dict(header=11,
                          index_col=1,
                          skipfooter=10)
}
```

and then call

```
df1 = pd.read_excel(input_location+'example1.xlsx', **read_excel_params['example1.xlsx'])
df2 = pd.read_excel(input_location+'example1.xlsx', **read_excel_params['example2.xlsx'])
```

You can stick the first argument in the dictionary as well as in `lo=input_location+'example1.xlsx` but you need to be careful to initialize `input_location` at the right moment, before the dictionary is created

The config dictionary can be populated outside your `read_files()` function and passed as an argument to this function. You can even then loop over different entries in the dict and call read_excel in a loop, without explicitly calling `read_excel` in your function for each file.